# Material UI limit tags - How can I select all data from DB clicking first tag saying like "select all"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to make MUI - limit tag. First, when the user clicks the first element which is "select all", the rest of the data will be added to small chips at once.

https://codesandbox.io/s/qzdzoh?file=/demo.tsx

[image]

Is there any source that I can figure it out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `Autocomplete` to [controlled state](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#controlled-states) by using `value` and `onChange` instead of `defaultValue`.

Next, you can add `"Select All"` option with an identifier key like `isSelectAll: true` to your options.

After that, you can handle the *"select all"* condition inside of `onChange` event.

Your code can be like this:

```js
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  //...
];

const top100FilmsWithSelectAll = [
  { title: "Select All", isSelectAll: true },
  ...top100Films
];

export default function LimitTags() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e, newValue) => {
    const isSelectAll = newValue.findIndex((v) => v.isSelectAll) > -1;
    if (isSelectAll) {
      setValue([...top100Films]);
    } else {
      setValue(newValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      limitTags={2}
      id="multiple-limit-tags"
      options={top100FilmsWithSelectAll}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="limitTags" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
      sx={{ width: "500px" }}
    />
  );
}
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-autocomplete-select-all?file=src%2FApp.jsx) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: You are 100000000% correct. Thank you so much! I needed to add some more functions for my task. However, it is beneficial! It was "value" problem. :)